# How do I delete a value from an Object-based associative array in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need to remove the value associated with a property in a Flex 3 associative array; is this possible?

For example, suppose I created this array like so:

```
var myArray:Object = new Object();
myArray[someXML.@attribute] = "foo";
```

Later, I need to do something like this:

```
delete myArray[someXML.@attribute];
```

However, I get this error message at runtime:

```
Error #1119: Delete operator is not supported with operand of type XMLList.
```

How do I perform this operation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

delete doesn't do as much in AS3 as it did in AS2:

http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/understanding_t.html

However, I think your problem might be solved by simply using toString(), i.e.

```
var myArray:Object = new Object();
myArray[someXML.@attribute.toString()] = "foo";

delete myArray[someXML.@attribute.toString()];
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than delete it, try setting the value to null.

```
myArray[someXML.@attribute] = null;
```

That way it'll end up the same as any other value in the array that isn't defined.

Comment: It's not quite "the same" - that'll leave a value on the object which is set to null. Delete is better if you want to remove it entirely; that way if you're doing something like a for each on the object you don't encounter that null "deleted" value.